# I am trying to combine observations in SAS

Tags: sas, dataset, data-manipulation

(NOTE: this dataset is completely fabricated and contains no actual information about any person or entity)

I have a dataset that has three variables in the following format:

```
COV_ID            Adj_zip          Claim_info

PSX0002915A       98216            A-20

PSX0002915A       98216            T-14

PSX0002920A       98216            A-16

PSX0002902A       98216            T-08

etc.
```

All observations are duplicated with the exception of 'Claim_info'.  I need to create a new variable called technician_info that will hold the information of claim_info if the claim_info observation starts with the letter T.  Essentially I need it to look like this:

```
COV_ID            Adj_zip          Claim_info    Technician_info

PSX0002915A       98216            A-20           T-14

PSX0002920A       98216            A-16           T-08
```

I don't exactly how to ask this question, so I tried to provide an example.  Any and all help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite a few ways to do this.

Here I split the input data into A records and T records.  Then I use PROC SQL to join the tables.

If you find this is taking a long time, let me know and I can adjust to something that might run faster for you.

```
data test;
format COV_ID $12.;
input COV_ID $  Adj_zip Claim_info $;

datalines;
PSX0002915A 98216 A-20
PSX0002915A 98216 T-14
PSX0002902A 98216 A-16
PSX0002902A 98216 T-08
;
run;

data As Ts;
set test;
if substr(claim_info,1,1) = 'A' then
    output As;
else if substr(claim_info,1,1) = 'T' then
    output Ts;
run;

proc sql noprint;
create table want as
select a.cov_id,
       a.adj_zip,
       a.claim_info,
       b.claim_info as Technician_info
    from As as a
      inner join
        Ts as b
    on a.cov_id = b.cov_id;
quit;
```

Comment: This is great.  Thank you so much.  I didn't think about breaking them into two data sets.  Thank you again.